# Buses from Hong Kong airport to Tsim Sha Tsui

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, hong-kong, hkg

Which buses can I take to get from the Hong Kong airport to 36-44 Nathan Rd, Tsim Sha Tsui, Hong Kong? Which ones are the most convenient in terms of the proximity of the destination bus stop and/or fare? (If that matters, I plan to take the bus around 7-8PM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Red circle indicates where 36-44 Nathan Road is. From airport, walk to the bus terminus to town. It's to the very right of arrival hall after immigration and customs. Take [Bus Route A21](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-A21-A21-D.pdf) towards Hung Hom MTR Station and get off at Middle Road stop (circled blue). Then walk back a block.

A21 belongs to a series of bus routes dedicated for airport connection. Its fleet of buses comes with luggage rack. The bus trip costs HKD$33. Prepare exact fare or use an Octopus Card.

I recommend *against* taking the MTR (except Airport Express) with heavy luggages. A bag or two is fine; taking MTR with heavy luggages in evening rush hour is asking for trouble.

Alternative route for cheaper fare; uses MTR:

- [Bus S1](http://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-S1-S1-D.pdf) ($3.5) to Tung Chung MTR Station; MTR Tung Chung Line to Lai King; (walk across opposite platform for) MTR Tsuen Wan Line to Tsim Sha Tsui. ($16.9 for Octopus Card; $19.5 for Single Journey Ticket) Exit L1 of Tsim Sha Tsui/East Tsim Sha Tsui Station (green circle in map) is around the corner of your destination.

Comment: I was wondering which option is faster -- A21 or S1+MTR?

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to take the Airport Express to Kowloon and take the complimentary shuttle bus to TST. There are three such buses, K3, K4 and K5, for different parts of TST (because it's a busy and crowded region). Find out which one goes closest to your destination: [bus info](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/complom_free_bus.html).

Comment: K3 will drop you off at the Holiday Inn Golden Mile which is just next door.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you absolutely need to take a bus, the best path is by the MTR.

Take the Airport Express to Hong Kong.

Walk to Central (it is a relatively long walk, but all indoors with moving walkways).

Take the Tsuan Wan Line to Tsim Sha Tsui.

Comment: Or take a the star ferry from central. More fun, if you have the time and not much luggage

Comment: I would not recommend this unless OP has no luggages. Taking MTR Admiralty -> Tsim Sha Tsui with luggage during evening rush hour is not a very good idea.

Comment: @LinkNg Yeah, but I find MTR no different than any other subway with luggage, and better then many...especially New York.  Everywhere, including the airport, is a hassle with too many bags.  A quick scan of the platform will get you a relatively uncrowded car.

Comment: @Johns-305 Finding a less crowded car in Central may be feasible, but with the crowd that boards the train in Admiralty, OP may find it a bit difficult to alight later.

Comment: HKD$10 more expensive than getting off at Kowloon station for a circuitous route. Not to mention the Central - Tsim Sha Tsui section is one of the most overcrowded parts in the MTR.